# "No server available to handle the request" thrown by AWS Elasticsearch Service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

It doesn't happen regularly, but I was able to catch it in my debugger:

[image]

And then, because of that trailing comma, things further complicate. That error is not even well formatted JSON, which makes it throw **DeserializationError**, which is how it reaches my code. We can ignore this one, I just needed to bitch about it a little bit.

How do we find why is the "No server available to handle the request" happening? How to mitigate this?

If this is the expected behavior of an overloaded ES cluster, how do we properly handle this error specifically?

Here are the health metrics:
[image]

Here's context around the error:
[image]

Comment: How do the health metrics look like on AWS for that node?

Comment: @Val added them at the bottom of the question.

Comment: health looks good. Are you hitting your nodes directly or are you going through a load balancer of some sort?

Comment: @Val directly from Lambdas on AWS.

Comment: Anything useful in the headers? Care to paste them in your question?

Comment: @Val Please clarify which headers : ) I'm using [this library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) to talk to Elasticsearch Service

Comment: Whatever is in the `headers` hash on your screenshot

Comment: @Val Sorry, I still don't get it : / I can't find anything meaningful under the "headers" keyword on that page

Comment: On your screenshot, in the debug window, there's an object called `headers` can you show its content?

Comment: Oh dear! I thought you were talking about the AWS console xD Let me catch that event again, and I'll let you know.

Comment: @Val finally caught it. I attached it at the bottom. Feel free to ask anything else.

Comment: Have you verified all these points (especially the first two)? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticsearch-http-503-errors/?nc1=h_ls